# JMeter GWT Escape Character Exception

Tags: gwt, jmeter, performance-testing, rpc, load-testing

I'm trying a test in JMeter for requests that include a regular expression in its body. Trying to re-run the test, I get the below exception:
//EX[,,["com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibaleRemoteServiceException", "Unexpected escape character after backslash

The request body under the recording controller looks something like: 
^([\w\-\.\'+]+)@(([([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}])) 
While the request in "View Results Tree" is like: 
^([\w-.\']+)@(([([0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}]))

Can anyone help please?

Comment: can you show more about your plan, regexp and request ? thx

Comment: The request body under the recording controller looks something like:
^([\\w\\-\\.\\'+]+)@((\\[([0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\\]))

While the request in "View Results Tree" is like:
^([\\w\-\.\']+)@((\[([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\]))

Comment: can you update the question to show part of the plan , request and response ? otherwise it will be hard to help

Comment: this cannot be the request, you are showing thr request. Show all View Results tree tabs for the failing request and also the one from which you extract the data

Comment: @Robert: Is [`^([\w.'+-]+)@((?:[0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3})`](https://regex101.com/r/mK8sX7/1) working for you? Or in View Results, [`^([\w.'-]+)@((?:[0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3})`](https://regex101.com/r/bO3rI7/1).

Comment: The first one; ^([\w.'+-]+)@((?:[0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}).
This is how it was recorded, but after executing the test, displays as the second one; which is incorrect